# Globe Willow keeps going into shock

Tags: trees, diseases

I live in Northern Arizona and globe willows do really well around here. However, I am having the opposite problem. Mine has went into shock twice this year. The first time I trimmed the dead branches back to the healthy ones. Now its in shock again (If I have my diagnosis right) and looks like the whole tree is almost dead besides some fresh growth. Any ideas how to stop this and get this tree back to healthy?[image]

Comment: Did you purchase this tree as a ball and burlap or a bare root tree?  How long has this tree been planted?  Something is very wrong, looks pretty bleak, I am sorry.  Tell us about how you water, what you did when transplanting/preparing your hole, did you fertilize?  Did you use anything on your lawn for pesticides?  Looks like you might need to pull the entire thing out and begin again, though not the same species anywhere near this tree's home.  More information!  Thanks...

Comment: I have to agree with stormy here. It appears you have had a bad sapling and things just never got better. This happens sometimes. I would also get the nursery involved if possible. If you are very determined to try and save the tree, you can keep trying. Get a soil test, talk to a local agricultural college or master gardeners group and even the nursery where you got this if possible. I would dig up the whole thing, add new soil, very little fertilizer, give it water and watch what happens.

Comment: Nice questions Srihari... but I'm a bit reticent as this tree is too large to be dug up and replanted.  It would be good to check those roots out for disease before replacing this tree with any species.  Are you a  Master Gardener?  Great idea about going back to the nursery.  This is not a common problem with willows.  The green grass shows the tree has gotten plenty of water even being in AZ!  I'd like to see the roots/root ball...and whether or not this was B&B or bare root when planted.  Something is very wrong...

Comment: Thanks for you comments, This is no good at all. I purchsed in a 15 gallon container from a local wholesaler who has a great reputation. I planted with a bag of good mulch around the roots and nursery soil. It gets lots of water. The tree did great the first year, just hit shock twice this year. However there is already new growth. Just sucks to see this cycle.

Comment: If there is new growth, there is still promise. Check for diseases as Stormy has indicated.

Comment: Stormy, I am not one yet, I have applied and hope to get into the program starting here in CA for next year. Are you one?